# Is there a way to embed facebook pictures on my website, which also allows likes, comments etc?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is there a way to display facebook pics on my website, which allows a user to Like, Comment etc FROM my website?  I want to display a photo gallery of my facebook page (which is public) but with the ability of users being able to like it, comment etc.

Comment: For those who still need this feature, unfortunately there's still no way for users to like and comment on Facebook photo album on website. But you can still display or embed it. You can use website plugins such as the one in this tutorial https://www.displaysocialmedia.com/embed-show-display-facebook-photo-album-on-website/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After MUCH digging around I found exactly what I was looking for, and no need for SDK!!

**How to Embed Facebook Posts**

Facebook introduced an “embedded posts” feature to help you embed any Facebook post – you can embed photographs, videos or regular status updates – on another website or blog. For instance, if a celebrity has shared a photograph on his or her Facebook Page, you can easily embed that image on your website by adding a single line of code.

You may embed any content that’s shared on Facebook Pages and personal profiles as long as the content owner has set the visibility of that post to Public.

There’s a small catch though. Facebook has enabled the Embedded Posts functionality for a handful of big web publishers including CNN, Mashable and The Huffington Post. Everyone else will have to wait to see that Embed link alongside their Facebook content.

There’s however an easy workaround though that will let you embed any Facebook content on your website even if “Embedded Posts” are not officially available for that Facebook account.

**Embed Code for Embedded Posts**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="YOUR_URL_HERE"></div>
```

Open any Facebook Post and copy the permalink (permanent URL) of that post. You can right-click the date of the post to determine its permalink. Next replace YOUR_URL_HERE in the snippet above with the permalink that you just copied and paste the modified snippet anywhere in your website. Done!

If you wisht to embed another Facebook post on the same web page, you don’t have to copy-paste the entire snippet. Just add a new  element and set the value of href as the permalink of your Facebook Post. The video tutorial explains this in greater detail.

Here is a blogpost that explains it all:
http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-facebook-post/28151/

Comment: Be aware that Facebook's embedded posts are not even a little bit responsive-friendly, which can be a big problem if you're designing a responsive site.

Comment: @ChrisHeald if you remove the `data-width` attribute they are responsive. At least when they get loaded.

Comment: My comment was made over 2 years ago - I'm sure things have changed since.

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box solution that I know of -

What I would do is build an application on facebook using the facebook javascript sdk to put elements on the site.

First thing you'll need to do is get folks to login - Once you've got that, you can display the photos, comment box and like boxes pretty easily, if you're familiar with javascript at all.

Facebook also has a bunch of plugins for comments / likes and whatnot, but no photos atm.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

I have build a similar application using Facebook SDK for Javascript. Just follow few simple steps as shown below.

Step 1: Initialize Javascript SDK for FB

Step 2: FBlogin using javascript SDK

Step 3: Using graph API get the JSON for photos URL..for Example:

FB.api('/me/photos', function(response) { console.log(response.data.picture)}

```
 "data": [
    {
      "id": "4864649943833", 
      "from": {
        "name": "XYZ", 
        "id": "1524800660"
      }, 
      "name": "From left to right: A, B& C!", 
      "picture": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/481890_4824639963833_259133397_s.jpg", 
      "source": "http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/481890xyz_4864549843833_259133397_n.jpg", 
      "height": 405, 
      "width": 720, 
      "images": [
        {
          "height": 540, 
          "width": 960, 
          "source": "http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/481890_4864649943833_259133397_n.jpg"
        },
```

Step 4: if you want to display friends photo galleries, get the access token first and get /me/friends/photos or /me//photos

Step 5: Follow the URL to incorporate likes and comments for the photos.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graph api of facebook to retrieve various JSON feeds including photo information. However if you intend to use facebook's own like and comment options, these are only based per url, you couldn't do it for actual images. One way around that is to have 1 image per url.